# Ubuntu 13.04, how to upgrade to GNOME 3.8.x

Tags: gnome, apt, updates

I'd like to update GNOME but I don't want 3.10 until a few extensions I use are updated. Can I specify a version to update with apt-get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `apt-cache policy` the current version of Gnome in the repositories is 3.8:

```
user@host:~$ apt-cache policy gnome
gnome:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:3.8+4ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:3.8+4ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
```

So you should be able to upgrade just fine currently.

<sup>Note I'm running 13.10, but it should be the same in 13.04. Run `apt-cache policy gnome` to double check</sup>

Comment: Apparently I somehow have 12.04 and thought it was 13.04... sigh.. #newguy

Comment: @user215559 Are you sure? After a look at ubuntu packages it appears Gnome 3.4 is the latest version for 13.04 as well..